# Getting returning value from multithreading in python 3

Tags: multithreading

I'm trying to get one or several returning values from a thread in a multithreading process. The code I show get cycled with no way to interrupt it with Ctrl-C, Ctrl+D.

```
import queue as Queue
import threading

class myThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, threadID, name, region):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.region = region
   def run(self):
      GetSales(self.region)

def GetSales(strReg): 
    print("Thread-" + strReg)
    return "Returning-" + strReg

def Main():

    RegionList = []
    RegionList.append("EMEA")
    RegionList.append("AP")
    RegionList.append("AM")

    # Create threads
    threads = []
    x = 0
    for region in RegionList:
        x += 1
        rthread = myThread(x, "Thread-" + region, region)   # Create new thread
        rthread.start()                                     # Start new thread
        threads.append(rthread)                             # Add new thread to threads list



    que = Queue.Queue()

    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
        result = que.get()
        print(t.name + " -> Done")

Main()
```

If I comment line "result = que.get()" the program runs with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is future and async management.

Firstly, your program loop indefinitely because of the line `que.get()`, because there is nothing in the queue, it wait that something happen, which will never happen. You don't use it.

---

What you want to do is an async task and get the result :

```py
import asyncio

async def yourExpensiveTask():
    // some long calculation
    return 42

async main():
    tasks = []
    tasks += [asyncio.create_task(yourExpensiveTask())]
    tasks += [asyncio.create_task(yourExpensiveTask())]

    for task in tasks:
        result = await task
        print(result)
```

See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html